# Why cannot I map an DSF/SMB share using New-SmbGlobalMapping?

Tags: powershell, server-message-block, dfs

I've got a DFS folder: `\\my.domain\Storage$`
I'd like to map it to a particular Windows Server Core machine using the `New-SmbGlobalMapping` PowerShell command using specific credentials.

Alas, when I attempt to do so I get a `The network name cannot be found` error. I know for a fact that the network name itself is OK because I can simply `cd` from PowerShell into that DFS folder...

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/299.

Apparently this was intentional (not a bug) and the documentation was updated to reflect it.  Unfortunately, there's no commitment to address this, just a "we may fix this" statement.

I can't find any reference to this issue in the [New-SmbGlobalMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/new-smbglobalmapping?view=windowsserver2022-ps&viewFallbackFrom=windowsserver2019-ps) docs online, and we don't update the built-in help, so I'm not sure if it's been addressed there.

There is a brief note in the [Persistent Storage in Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/persistent-storage) documentation, though.